# PLacing Order Magento 2.1 REST API

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5a291a13d9760

I am using Magento 2.1

I am hitting the url to place order:-

```
Method:- PUT

https://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/ddaae427f0a12acf52a73b056b78++++/order
```

My Payment Method is COD!

I am sending in Body

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "code": "cashondelivery",
        "title": "Cash On Delivery"
    }
}
```

Expected result:
Order_ID

Actual result it is returning:

```
{
    "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5a291a13d9760"
}
```

Log.FILE:
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5a291a13d9760; Message: Property "Code" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface". in /var/www/vhosts/myserverexample.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/‌​framework/Webapi/Err‌​orProcessor.php:195

Comment: Could you also add the content of a log file?

Comment: Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5a291a13d9760; Message: Property "Code" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface". in /var/www/vhosts/myserverexample.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Magento-2, the place order is done by the function `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()` and it is defined in two model files. 
For guest user , it is invoked from the model `\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement` and it takes 4 arguments.

**1) Quote Id**

**2) email**

**3) Instance of the \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface** in to which the Payment Method parameters should be set.

The parameters that should be set for the payment method interface should be the following,

**a) method**

**b) po_number**

**c) additional_data**

If you are custom setting these parameters, you can set this parameters by using the `setData()` method of the `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface` interface instance.

In your case, since the payment method is Cash On Delivery, you should send the payment method parameters in the following way,

```
{
 "paymentMethod": {
    "method": "cashondelivery",
    "po_number": null,
    "additional_data": null
 } 
}
```

**4) The fourth and last parameter for the savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder() function for guest place order, is the billing address which should be set with the \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface interface instance.**

For Logged-In customer, the place order is happening through the `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()` function from the model `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement` and it takes 3 parameters.

**1) Quote Id**

**2) Payment method parameters set to the instance of the `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface`**

**3) Billing address parameters set to the instance of `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface interface`**

As per my view, your stated error may be fixed if you send the payment method details in the following format,

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
    "method": "cashondelivery",
    "po_number": null,
    "additional_data": null
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks But it is responding now       {
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "customerId",
        "fieldValue": null
    }
}

Comment: Are you placing order for a logged in customer ?

Comment: Can you please post the billing address parameters which you are sending

Comment: yes i am passing token also for log in

Comment: can you post the format of your entire input data here?

Comment: i am posting in shipping-information                                
"shipping_address": {
            "firstname": "Your name",
            "lastname": "your last name",
            "city": "India",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "region": "Region",
            "postcode": "123456",
            "telephone": "1234567",
            "region_id": 0,
            "street": ["Line1", "Line2"],
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_address_id": 1
        }

Comment: { "addressInformation": {
        "shipping_address": {
        },
        "billing_address": {
            "firstname": "Your name",
            "lastname": "your last name",
            "city": "India",
            "country_id": "IN",
            "region": "Region",
            "postcode": "123456",
            "telephone": "1234567",
            "region_id": 0,
            "street": ["Line1", "Line2"],
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_address_id": 1
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
  }
}

Comment: Make sure the customer exists for the customer_id=1. Try placing order for another customer.

Comment: can you please provide me all step to place order through magento 2.1 REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send such a data through webapi. As you can see:

```
/**
 * Get purchase order number
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getPoNumber();

/**
 * Set purchase order number
 *
 * @param string $poNumber
 * @return $this
 */
public function setPoNumber($poNumber);

/**
 * Get payment method code
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMethod();

/**
 * Set payment method code
 *
 * @param string $method
 * @return $this
 */
public function setMethod($method);

/**
 * Get payment additional details
 *
 * @return string[]|null
 */
public function getAdditionalData();

/**
 * Set payment additional details
 *
 * @param string $additionalData
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAdditionalData($additionalData);
```

There is no code or title setter/getter in payment method interface. To set code you should use "method" instead and set title in additional data array.

In short, all data that can be passed through webapi must have related setter/getter configured in appropriate interface. This is exactly what your error in log saying: **Message: Property "Code" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface"**

You might ask, which properties can I use then?
Read the interface again, you will see that method, poNumber, additionaldata got relevant setter/getters and these are attributes you can set through api call.

**Update:**

Actually you can't set title of payment method. There is no such a field in payment's table. All you can do is to set data as interface allow. Title will be eventually derived from object because it is defined in a particular payment class and not stored in database.

Comment: how to set Additional data array for title?

Comment: Here is the response of payment-methods call      [
    {
        "code": "cashondelivery",
        "title": "Cash On Delivery"
    }
]

Comment: if I am not passing title, Response is   {
    "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue",
    "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "customerId",
        "fieldValue": null
    }
}

Comment: Give me whole request you are sending.

Comment: 1) https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts  2) https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/d6042a9b05356df88882b326b++++/items   3) https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/d6042a9b05356df88882b326b++++/shipping-information  4) https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/d6042a9b05356df88882b326b++++/order

Comment: 1) rest/V1/guest-carts         2) rest/V1/guest-carts/cart-id/items             3) rest/V1/guest-carts/cart-id/shipping-information     4) 3) rest/V1/guest-carts/cart-id/order